# open source tool for creating stateful mocks using swagger spec

Tags: open-source, api, rest

Can anyone suggest any open source tool for creating stateful mocks using swagger spec. Motive is to get dynamic responses which returns state of object so that complete flow of an application can be tested using those mocks.